# Convergence of $a_{n+2} = \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+a_n}}$, with $a_1=\sqrt{7}$, $a_2 = \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

How to prove the convergence of the real sequence $\{a_n\}$,  which is defined by $a_{n+2} = \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+a_n}}$,  with $a_1=\sqrt{7}$,  $a_2 = \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7}}$?  Furthermore, how to verifty that 2 is the limit?

Comment: Isn't $a_n$ monoton and bounded?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be monotonic, by computation, although it converges to $2$ very quickly.

Comment: As to the last question you pose, *if* you can prove the sequence converges to some limit $L$, then $L=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+L}}$.

Comment: how about you study separately $$b_n = a_{2n-1}$$ and $$c_n = a_{2n},$$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. We have $$b_{n+1} = f(b_n)$$ and $$c_{n+1} = f(c_n),$$ with $$f(x) = \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x}}$$

Comment: @dfnu Yeah,  I've tried this method.  But it is a bit clumsy.  $b_n$ and $c_n$ should be further divieded into two subsubsequences, in order to posses the monotonicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to see that $0 \le a_n \le \sqrt{7}$. Then $$|a_{n+2}-a_{m+2}|=\frac{|\sqrt{7+a_n}-\sqrt{7+a_m}|}{\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+a_n}}+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+a_m}}} \le \frac{|\sqrt{7+a_n}-\sqrt{7+a_m}|}{\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7}}}+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7}}}} < $$ $$ <|\sqrt{7+a_n}-\sqrt{7+a_m}|=\frac{|a_n-a_m|}{ \sqrt{7+a_n}+\sqrt{7+a_m}} \le \frac{|a_n-a_m|}{ \sqrt{7}+\sqrt{7}} <\frac{|a_n-a_m|}{5}$$ Since $|a_{n+2}-a_{m+2}|<\frac{|a_n-a_m|}{5}$ then $|a_{n+2N}-a_{m+2N}|<\frac{|a_n-a_m|}{5^N} \le \frac{\sqrt{7}}{5^N}$. Since $|a_{n+2N}-a_{m+2N}|< \frac{\sqrt{7}}{5^N}$ then sequence $a_n$ is Cauchy sequence. Then by Cauchy Convergence Criterion (http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-cauchy-convergence-criterion) the sequence $a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Thank you so much,  What a  Nice and Clear Proof it is !!!